# nullity and rank of the linear transformation $T: T [ p (x)]= p(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of all polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $\le n$. if $p$ belongs to $V$ and $q = T(p)$, means that $q(x) = p(x+1)$ for all real $x$. find nullity and rank of the linear transformation $T$.

**Attempt:** Let $p(x) \in V : T[p(x)] = p(x+1) = 0.$

Now, any such polynomial which satisfies the above relation can be expressed in terms of the $n+1$ dimensional basis: $1,t,t^2,\cdots,t^n$.

I am confused why my textbook says that the nullity is $0$.

Similarly, the rank should be also equal to $n+1?$

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: Ýou have $T\colon V\longrightarrow V$. The nullity of $T$ is the dimension of the $V$-subspace $\{p(x)\in V\colon p(x+1)=0_V\}$. What set is this?

Comment: @GitGud uhm, so, $p(x+1) = 0_v \implies p(x+1)$ is the constant zero function $\implies p(x) = 0$. Hence, nullity is $0$? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I got terribly confused.

Comment: @GitGud Regarding the rank of this linear transformation. The rank of the linear transformation is the dimension of the set $\{T[p(x)]: p(x) \in V\}$. Such a set is clearly of infinite cardinality as there are infinite polynomials in $V$. Hence, it's dimension should be infinite?

Comment: Consider the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R^2$. What is the dimension of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: it's $2$ as $\mathbb R^2 = \{ (x,y) : x,y \in \mathbb R \}$ there are two tuples in each elements of $\mathbb R^2$.  Here, Range $T = \{ T [ p(x) ] : p(x) \in V?$ And there infinite such $p(x)$ in $V$?

Comment: But $\mathbb R^2$ has infinite cardinality. This where I'm getting at. It's true that $\{T(p): p \in V\}$ has infinite cardinality, but that doesn't say anything about its dimension. What is the dimension of $V$? First answer this and then use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Ohkay.. Dimension of $V = n+1$. By the rank nullity theorem : $n+1 = ~rank~null~T + ~rank~range~T \implies ~rank~range~T = n+1$

Comment: Correct. Make sure you're able to complete the details. I'd appreciate it if you posted an answer after you get everything down.

Comment: @GitGud Done.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation For the null space**:

Nullity of $T$ is the dimension of the subspace $\{p(x) \in V : p(x+1) = 0_v\}$

Now, $p(x+1)$ is a constant zero function means that $p(x)=0$ which means nullity = $0$.

**Explanation for Range Space**

The range space refers to the set of all elements $\{T[p(x)] = p(x+1): p(x) \in V \}$

Now, the set of all the polynomials in $V$ can be sufficiently represented using the basis : $1,t,t^2,\cdots,t^{n }.$ Hence, the range space's dimension is $n+1$.

The same can be arrived at using the rank nullity theorem as well.

Comment: Before I up vote, quiz: why does $x\mapsto p(x+1)$ being constantly $0$ imply that $p$ is constantly $0$?

Comment: $p(x+1) = 0 $ is valid for all $x \in \mathbb R.$ Hence, it should be valid for any $x-1$ as well. Substituting, we get $p(x)=0$?

Comment: I don't quite get your argument, so I won't say it's wrong. Here's how I see it. Let $f$ be the map $x\mapsto x+1$, note that $f$ is injective. From $p\circ f=\bf 0$, one gets $p\circ f \circ f^{-1}=\mathbf{0}\circ f^{-1}$and finally $p=\bf 0$, where $\bf 0$ denotes the map $x\mapsto 0$

Comment: Ohkay . I actually meant that if a function $p(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $p(x-1)=0$ for all $x$

Comment: That much I got, but so what? How to go from there to $p$ being null?

Comment: So, then if $p(y+1) = 0 \forall y \in \mathbb R \implies $ this relation is valid for any $y = x-1; x \in \mathbb R$ as well. Substituting, $p(x)=0$. Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: It's perfectly fine, I had a brain fart. Sorry.

Comment: Np :) ${}{}{}{}$